# how to calculate precision, recall, and accuracy of classification with R?

Tags: r

I am new with R and really struggling with it.
There is set of data with one label of classification.

```
fit <- lm(class~.,data=train) 
pred <- predict(fit,newdata=test)
```

I have the code such as ↑, also I know the formula of precision and recall. Just I can figure out how to write it with R.
I plan to try `r package ROCR`, but there is

```
pred <- prediction( ROCR.simple$predictions, ROCR.simple$labels)
```

and I do not understand what is `labels`.

Comment: Labels is the ground truth per prediction, e.g. the predicted instance is truly positive or truly negative.

Comment: @MarcClaesen could you be more detailed? thx!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how to use R.

Comment: It's about R but there is not yet enough detail to provide a correct response. Post more code and better description of the train and test datasets.

Answer (score 3):

The ROCR package has an example of precision and recall. Here's the code, putting your model as the input.

```
p1 <- predict(fit, newdata=test)

library(ROCR)
pred <- prediction(p1,test$class)
perf <- performance(pred,"prec","rec")

plot(perf, avg= "threshold", colorize=T, lwd= 3,
   main= "... Precision/Recall graphs ...")
plot(perf, lty=3, col="grey78", add=T)
```

Notice that there are a few steps.

1. Train the model (`fit`).
2. Predict the outcome on a new dataset (`p1`).
3. Use the prediction command in RORC (`pred`), inputing the predicted values and the real values, here these are `p1` and `test$class`.
4. Use the performance function to calculate the precision and recall, inputting the result of step 3, `pred`.

Comment: How do you modify this so you're looking at the train data so you create a plot on the trained model instead?